# Is there a way to rebind the unary minus (negate) to a different typeclass than Num?

Tags: haskell

As I understand it, the unary minus is the only unary operator in Haskell and it is bound to `Num`'s `negate`? Is there way to rebind the unary minus to a `negate` in a different typeclass?

Comment: you can avoid prelude (`-XNoImplicitPrelude`) and then define it however you want. the problem is that most libraries implicitly depend on the prelude so it will be very lonely

Comment: I tried just hiding negate during import and it did not work.

Comment: oh wait, i forgot. ignore me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [the RebindableSyntax extension](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/guest-posts/2014-12-06-rebindable-syntax.html). It allows the unary minus to refer to whatever "negate" is in scope. As the [docs say](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=rebindable#ghc-flag--XRebindableSyntax):

> - Negation (e.g. “- (f x)”) means “negate (f x)”, both in numeric patterns, and expressions.

The compiler has this convention hardcoded but can be persuaded otherwise as long as you

- Turn on `RebindableSyntax`, which implicitly turns on `NoImplicitPrelude`;
- Hide the default `negate` when you import the Prelude; and
- Define your own `negate` in scope.

Comment: It seems I have to define a bunch of things apart from negate. I needed to also define ifThenElse (using pattern matching) and import fromString, but now it works. Thanks. ...And actually, rather than use a global standard ifThenElse, it occurs to me now that I could make it a part of the typeclass definition for my DSL. That is quite neat.